# Прохождение цикла по списку

Tags: python, python-3.6

Есть список с такой структурой:

```
[('Броня', [2, 0.6747547826210327])]
```

Как можно пройтись по нему циклом, но, при этом, нужно, чтобы `('Броня', [2, 0.6747547826210327])` считалось за один элемент, и в цикле можно было взаимодействовать по типу `data[0], #Броня data[1] #[2, 0.6747547826210327]`

Моя попытка не увенчалась успехом, он проходит по каждому отдельно.

Comment: `data[i][0]` и `data[i][1]`, где `i` - переменная цикла или: `[(a, b) for a, b in data]`

Comment: Приведите код вашей попытки. Это же обычный цикл `for`, насколько я понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужен простой цикл `for`. Для примера:

```
lst = [('Броня', [2, 0.6747547826210327])]
for data in lst:
    print(data[0], 'с характеристиками', data[1])
```

Comment: а если нужно выбирать по индексу и таких элементов в массиве допустим 3

Comment: @Cookie первый элемент будет `lst[0]`, второй - `lst[1]`. Чтобы получить, например, название очередного элемента `lst[0][0]`

Answer (score 2):

идиоматический обход списка на python:

```
array = [('Броня1', [2, 0.6747547826210327]), ('Броня2', [2, 0.6747547826210327]), ('Броня3', [2, 0.6747547826210327])]

for armor in array:
    print(armor[0], armor[1])
```

вывод:

```
Броня1 [2, 0.6747547826210327]
Броня2 [2, 0.6747547826210327]
Броня3 [2, 0.6747547826210327]
```